# Rails_admin, logging in with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-admin

In [rails_admin wiki with Devise](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Devise) it has example with only one model. I have two models `Admin` and `Owner`. I will define their roles with `cancancan`.

Is it possible to make more than one model, which uses Devise, able to login to rails_admin dashboard? I just can't find any examples.

Using only one model with diffrent roles may be bad solution, because there each of them will have very different attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method I have found is to use inheritance.

I have `Admin` and `User` models in which I want to use my rails_admin. I have created `Person` model which will be parent class for both of them.

Then I added devise for `Person` with CanCan authorization.